# Append a value of a JSON inside another JSON in JMeter

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter

By using the following script, I am able to generate the request payload for a request method.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
def builder = new JsonBuilder()
def finalRequest = [:];
def dicomTemp = builder.dicomTemplate
    {
    templateName "Default"
    templateDesc "Default"
    templateType "DEFAULT"
    }
def dicomTags = builder.dicomTaS {
    {
    tagGroup "0002"
    tagElement "0002"
    tagName "Media Storage SOP Class UID"
    updatedOn "2021-10-05T22:03:36.000+00:00"
    labelValue 131074
    mandatory "1"
    }
    {
    tagGroup "0002"
    tagElement "0010"
    tagName "Transfer Syntax UID"
    tagKeyword "TransferSyntaxUID"
    createdOn "2021-06-02T20:40:59.000+00:00"
    numericLabel "00020010"
    labelValue 131088
    mandatory "1"
    }
}
finalRequest.put('studyDTO', true);
finalRequest.put('allSites', true);
finalRequest.put('allSubjects', true);
finalRequest.put('allStates', true);
finalRequest.put('allVisits', true);
finalRequest.put('modalities', response.modalities);
finalRequest.put('allModalities', true);
finalRequest.put('allExamDates', true);
finalRequest.put('allSeries', true);
finalRequest.put('transferType', "DICOM");
finalRequest.put('sftpLocations', response.sftpLocations)
finalRequest.put('dicomLocations', response.dicomLocations)
finalRequest.put('customFolder', null)
finalRequest.put('folderStructure', null)
finalRequest.put('customFile', null)
finalRequest.put('fileStructure', null)
finalRequest.put('includePS', null)
finalRequest.put('softEditOverride', true)
finalRequest.put('dicomTemplate', dicomTemp.dicomTemplate)
finalRequest.put('dicomTemplate.dicomTags', [dicomTags.dicomTaS])
vars.put('finalPayload',new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(finalRequest).toPrettyString());
```

But there are two corrections require here,

[image]

The `dicomTags` should be a key of `dicomTemplate`, but it is placed separately because of the declaration `dicomTemplate.dicomTags`. How to rectify this?

[image]

Can see the second value, want to include all the values

[image]

Like below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change this:

```
def dicomTags = builder.dicomTaS {
{
  tagGroup "0002"
  tagElement "0002"
  tagName "Media Storage SOP Class UID"
  updatedOn "2021-10-05T22:03:36.000+00:00"
  labelValue 131074
  mandatory "1"
}
{
  tagGroup "0002"
  tagElement "0010"
  tagName "Transfer Syntax UID"
  tagKeyword "TransferSyntaxUID"
  createdOn "2021-06-02T20:40:59.000+00:00"
  numericLabel "00020010"
  labelValue 131088
  mandatory "1"
}
}
```

to this:

```
def dicomTags = builder {
    dicomTaS(
            [
                    {
                        tagGroup "0002"
                        tagElement "0002"
                        tagName "Media Storage SOP Class UID"
                        updatedOn "2021-10-05T22:03:36.000+00:00"
                        labelValue 131074
                        mandatory "1"
                    },
                    {
                        tagGroup "0002"
                        tagElement "0010"
                        tagName "Transfer Syntax UID"
                        tagKeyword "TransferSyntaxUID"
                        createdOn "2021-06-02T20:40:59.000+00:00"
                        numericLabel "00020010"
                        labelValue 131088
                        mandatory "1"
                    }
            ]
    )
}
```

and this:

```
finalRequest.put('dicomTemplate', dicomTemp.dicomTemplate)
finalRequest.put('dicomTemplate.dicomTags', [dicomTags.dicomTaS])
```

to this:

```
dicomTemp.dicomTemplate.put('dicomTags', dicomTags['dicomTaS'])
finalRequest.put('dicomTemplate', dicomTemp.dicomTemplate)
```

also [don't post code as screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) and include everything we need to reproduce your issue (i.e. `response` object): [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)